# Cannot open database requested in login 'Database1'. Login fails. Login failed for user 'sa'

Tags: vb.net

I got the above error when i deploy my web application into windows server 2003. How do i resolve it?

Login.aspx.vb

```
Dim connection As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("database").ConnectionString()

Dim mycon As New SqlConnection(connection)
```

Web.config

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="database" connectionString="Data Source='172.20.145.67';Initial Catalog='Database1';User ID='sa';Password='321'"/>
 </connectionStrings>
```

Stack Trace

```
[SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot open database requested in login 'Database1'. Login fails.
Login failed for user 'sa'.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +800131
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +186
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +1932
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK) +33
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, SqlConnection owningObject) +172
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(String host, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Int64 timerStart) +381
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +181
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +173
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection) +357
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options) +30
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject) +424
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject) +66
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject) +494
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection) +82
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) +105
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +111
   WebApplication1.Login.ImageButton2_Click(Object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e) in C:\Users\Pei Wen\Desktop\SHS\fyp final.16\WebApplication1\Login.aspx.vb:20
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton.OnClick(ImageClickEventArgs e) +86
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +115
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +7
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +11
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +33
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1746
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to quote strings inside the connection string.

`<add name="database" connectionString="Data Source=172.20.145.67;Initial Catalog=Database1;User ID=sa;Password=321"/>`

Comment: Please add this in connection string and try again.  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"

Comment: added but still having that error. 

<add name="database" connectionString="Data Source=172.20.145.67;Initial Catalog=Database1;User ID=sa;Password=321" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>

Comment: Can you connect to the database thru SQL Server Management Studio with the login: sa and password: 321 ?

Like this: http://ploader.net/files/d0cb35ca833f0f916568c3aaa256ed6f.png

Comment: Sry..where do i find SQL Server Management Studio? In the server machine?

Comment: On the server should be fine - Start Menu-> All Programs -> Microsoft SQL Server -> somewhere in there.

Comment: i can't find it. my server is using sql server 2000

Comment: Look for 'Enterprise Manager' for SQL Server 2000. Management Studio is for SQL 2005/8

Comment: i wasn't prompt for userid and pwd when i click it.

Comment: Sorry, its been a loooong time since I used SQL 2000 and Enterprise Manager, I can't remember exactly how the login box looks but somewhere on there it should allow you to choose HOW you connect (perhaps in a dropdown menu?) - you shouldn't choose 'Windows Authentication' in the menu on the login box, click it and choose the other option (SQL authentication I think). This should allow you to enter login and password.

If you're still stuck, take a screenshot of the login window, upload it to www.ploader.net and paste the link here.

Comment: sry..i can't find the login. Was it because i'm not the administrator?

Comment: http://www.hosting.com/support/sql/enterprise-manager  

Try following the instructions above to register and connect to a SQL 2000 database. Use sa/321 and let me know what happens.

If your PC can 'see' the server, try doing the steps with Enterprise Manager on your PC. Otherwise use the Enterprise Manager on the server.

Comment: What error are you getting when you try to register? And are you doing this on your PC or the Server ...?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply...i got the error "SQL Server does not exist or access denied ConnectionOpen[Connect[]]

Comment: i was able to login when i open up query analyzer

Comment: So tell us - what was the problem and the solution? The suspense is killing me!  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<add name="database" connectionString="Data Source=172.20.145.67;Initial Catalog=Database1;User ID=sa;Password=321"/>
```

To Remove single quote

Comment: Giving single quotes will convert the values to another format.

Comment: Please check your connection credentials by connecting with sql server.

Comment: what do you mean and how do i check?